# Jquery can't acceed attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I certainly put a stupid question, but i don't find the solution.

I try to access the attr of a checkbox, when i click on a checkbox i wanna do a json request to update value.
When i click on the checkbox i get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
```

here a part of my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var checked = + json[i].know == true?"checked": "";
    $("#container").append("<input type='checkbox' class='know-check' name='know' know-seq='"+i+"' value='Know' "+checked+">");
}
$('.know-check').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr());
});
```

I have try multiple things like

```
console.log($(this)[0]);
```

and i obtain

```
<input type=​"checkbox" class=​"know-check" name=​"know" know-seq=​"1" value=​"Know">​
```

but `console.log($(this)[0].attr());` give me the same error

i'm sure there is a simple solution, but i didn't have any idea, so if someone can help me :)

Thanks
ps: Sorry for the mistakes, i'm not English

Comment: since you are using an invalid attribute i suggest use `data-*` like `data-know-seq=​"1"` then get is as `$(this).attr("data-know-seq")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the attribute name as an argument to attr function.

```
$('.know-check').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("know-seq"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jquery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is not designed to be called without parameters, so pass the parameter name - `know-seq`

```
$('.know-check').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("know-seq"));
});
```